# Finding values of registers via AT&T syntax operands

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, att, addressing-mode

I'm a little confused about how to derive/calculate the values of registers. I've scoured several questions on SO and other websites but I can't find anyone who has addressed my question.

Here's where my confusion lies. Suppose we have the following memory addresses and registers:

```
Address    Value     |    Register     Value
-----------------------------------------------
0x100      0xFF      |    %eax         0x100
0x104      0xAB      |    %ecx         0x1
0x108      0x13      |    %edx         0x3
0x10C      0x11      |
```

I understand that in some cases you are supposed to add up the values of registers, while they are in hexadecimal form, such as the following. (By the way, forgive me if I get the syntax wrong, like putting equal signs when it's not conventionally used, but I just want to get my question across.)

```
9(%eax, %ecx) = (0x100 + 0x9 + 0x3) = (0x10C) = 0x11
```

Whereas in other cases, you are supposed to add them up in decimal form and then convert to hexadecimal form, such as the following.

```
260(%ecx, %edx) = (1 + 260 + 3) = (264) = (0x108) = 0x13
```

So my question is, **how do I know when to add them up in hexadecimal form or decimal form?**

Edit: Looks like I've figured it out. The displacement (number outside the brackets) is always in decimal form; if I want to add it up with other hex numbers, I obviously have to convert it into hex form too.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the issue is. The method of calculation (base + index + displacement) is correct, but since `0x100 + 0x9 + 0x3` = 268 and `1 + 260 + 3` = 264 ... is the expectation that the hex and decimal calculations reach the same memory address?

Comment: "how do I know when to add them up in hexadecimal form or decimal form" You can choose either form (or binary, or octal, or ...) and get the same numeric result. To determine whether your input is decimal or hexadecimal, look for the `0x` prefix or `h` suffix that indicates hex. (Except for some programs like 86 DOS Debug which always default to hexadecimal.)

Comment: @sj95126 So just to clarify... the displacement (the number outside the brackets?) is always in decimal form? And so I should convert it to hexadecimal form when adding with other hexadecimal numbers. Is that correct?

Comment: @MaximusT: The displacement can be in any valid number form and the assembler will convert it as necessary. So you can either write `0x100(....)` or `256(....)` regardless of the other arguments or how they were given values.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `%eax` holds `1` and `%ecx` holds `10`.

It is like C, every integer literal is decimal by default, unless you put a prefix `0x`

```
movl $10, 10(%eax, %ecx) # *(1 + 10 + 10) = 10
movl $10, 0x10(%eax, %ecx) # *(1 + 10 + 16) = 10
movl $0x10, 0x10(%eax, %ecx) # *(1 + 10 + 16) = 16
```

---

And, as a truly personal recommendation, Intel syntax is just better.

`movl $10, 10(%eax, %ecx, 4)` vs `mov [eax + ecx * 4 + 10], 10`

But it is up to you to decide.